# TCPDF weird charecture when converting from SVG file

Tags: svg, tcpdf

I am facing font issue in tcpdf. Actually i am generating pdf from SVG file and for some fonts like "alex-brush" showing weird characters like rectangle and question mark symbol in pdf. Although not showing in svg file (tested on browser).

Here is my Code:

```
require_once ('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', true);

$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(0);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(0);
$pdf->SetLeftMargin(0);
$pdf->SetRightMargin(0);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setCellMargins(0,0,0,0);
$pdf->SetCellPaddings(0,0,0,0);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
$pdf->SetDisplayMode(100);

$pdf->AddPage(); // Add page to pdf before addding content
//There are several other property need to be set on basis of your need

$folderName = 'Alex_Brush';
$fontFileName='AlexBrush';

$fontpath = "./tcpdf/fonts/googlefonts/".$folderName."/".$fontFileName."-Regular.ttf";
$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont($fontpath);
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 14, '', false);
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array($fontname, '', 10, '', false));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array($fontname, '', 8, '', false)); 

$pdf->ImageSVG('bpn.svg', $x=0, $y=0, $cwidth, $cheight, '', $align='center', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=TRUE);

$pdf->Output('/home/test/public_html/admin/my.pdf', 'F');
```

Comment: Post a minimal SVG that reproduces the problem, and preferably a link to the generated PDF.

Answer (score 0):

If your SVG contains extra whitespace (space, tabs, linefeeds) within your `text` or `tspan` elements, TCPDF may include it in the text added to the PDF.

Depending on the font, those characters may then be rendered as "unknown" (usually some sort of box with a question mark).

Stripping the whitespace from those elements should solve the problem.